# Is there a command to move up and down the sidebar file list in sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext2

I use the sidebar a lot in sublime text and I want some quick way of moving up and down the list ( preferably with a keybinding but if there is some command then I'm sure I can bind it).

For instance if I have 10 files in a folder then I can click on one and view it, but then I have to pick up the mouse to view the next or previous file. I want to be able to move to the next or previous file in the list.

I know I can use ctrl-p to search for the file but I was hoping to have a keyboard shortcut to simply move to the next file. Is there anything like this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you focus the sidebar with `Control+0` you can use the arrow keys to move up and down through the files. `Right Arrow` will open a folder and `Left Arrow` will close it.

Comment: This is one step to the right direction, however it is not the absolute solution. Here's why: in sidebar there's "open files" section and "folders" section. Most of the cases I need to move by "folders" (tree), not the opened files (I can use ctrl+<number> to move by them). But when I focus on sidebar arrows move selection by "open files" section first.

Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Additionally, you can press escape or ctrl-1 to return to the editor

Answer (score 1):

alt-1 , alt-numbers? for switching between tabs? open all 10 files first :P

Comment: Interesting idea I have to admit but not at all what I'm looking for because if I have a lot of files in a folder then it could get pretty confusing, but I'll bear it in mind if I don't get anything else as it would work for small numbers of files alright I'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can focus on the file you are editing and type `Ctrl + 0` which leads you to its position in the tree. Expanding the tree if it was collapsed. From there you can now move with the arrows (or VIM equivalent directions).

Then to move back, to edit any tree selected file, you can use the command `next_view` which by default is `super+shift+]`

on [*.sublime-keymap*](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/key_bindings.html) we can find that default.
`{ "keys": ["super+shift+]"], "command": "next_view" }`